# Не удается получать новые сообщения в процессе работы скрипта управления ботом Telegram

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

Я пишу скрипт для управления ботом через Bot API, состоящий из исполняемого PHP файла на моем сервере, на который настроен Webhook и к которому обращается мой бот при получении нового сообщения от пользователя. Но у меня проблема, что когда я получаю данные от бота по полученному сообщению, если я это делаю повторно когда скрипт уже запустился, я получаю только старое сообщение, и я не могу получить новое сообщение и обработать его в середине работы скрипта. Я хочу задать сложную логику с вложениями при обработке сообщений от пользователя, например:

```
$update = file_get_contents('php://input');///получение данных от бота
$update = json_decode($update, TRUE);///декодирование данных
$message = $update["message"]["text"];///назначение данных в переменную
switch($message) {////варьируем действия на основе изначально имеющегося ответа
   case "number1":
   ////отправляем что-нибудь пользователю и ждем ответа
   ////снова получаем, декодируем и назначаем обновленные данные
   $update = file_get_contents('php://input');
   $update = json_decode($update, TRUE);
   $message = $update["message"]["text"];
   switch($message) {////смотрим на новое сообщение
        case "number2":
        ////совершаем действия на основе полученного нового ответа
        }
   }
   ...
```

И когда я уже в процессе исполнения скрипта повторно пытаюсь получить и назначить в переменную $message новый ответ от пользователя, в результате получается только старый ответ (который имелся на момент старта работы скрипта), и поэтому я не могу варьировать логику дальнейшей работы. Что можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 1):

Надо вернуть на запрос код 200 и как минимум пустой JSON {} - как максимум - можно сформировать ответы пользователю, но! вы не узнаете что ответит вам сервер на это, после этого сервер считает что он доставил вам обновление.

Как вариант перейдите на long-polling - и передавайте последний update_id как параметр.